# Android: Write and read json string to file (full example)

Tags: android, json, string, file

In my Android Application I have a json string representing an array of objects. I just want to save this json string to a file and retrieve this json string at some other point in time (e.g. the next time the user opens the app).

This should be not too hard and similiar questions have been asked before. But all answers point to external ressources that only give half baked answers.

Please give a simple but full example of writing a long string (that happens to be in a json format representing an array of objects) to file and retrieving that string at a later point in time.

Comment: Is this appropriate for Stack Overflow? Is it even a question? Why don't you pull together all the half baked examples and attempt it yourself, and ask a question if you run into a problem?

Comment: This is not a question. Here is a very popular library for json in java https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. Try to implement it and if you get in trouble, then ask a proper question. And here is an example http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/